# Assembly paths for plugins, workflows, and supporting assemblies

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

So I've gotten this error message from time to time since working with MS CRM.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has
>   experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #C0916659

Since there are multiple places for DLLs to live it makes it a pain to maintain.

Here's what I know of so far.

**CRM SERVER**
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Server\bin - ?
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Server\bin\Assembly - *Plugins*
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Server\CRMWeb\bin - *Supporting DLLs for plugins*

**ASYNC SERVER**
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Server\bin\Assembly - *Async workflows and plugins*

What else am I missing or need to be corrected on how these paths work and their intended purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is to register the assemblies to the database.

> Plug-ins not-registered in the sandbox can be stored in the Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM server's database or the on-disk file system. **We strongly
>   recommend that you store your production-ready plug-ins in the
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM database, instead of on-disk. Plug-ins stored
>   in the database are automatically distributed across multiple
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM servers in a data center cluster.** On-disk
>   storage of plug-ins is useful for debugging plug-ins using Microsoft
>   Visual Studio but is mostly provided for backward compatibility with
>   callouts. You can debug a plug-in that is stored in the database.
>
> Plug-ins registered in the sandbox must be stored in the database
>   regardless of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM deployment (on-premises,
>   IFD/SPLA, or Online).

This excerpt from the MSDN describes the registration possibilities and the paths.

> For on-premises or Internet-facing Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>   installations, when you deploy plug-ins from another computer to the
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM server disk (on-disk deployment), the plug-in
>   assembly must be manually copied to the server before registration.
>   The assembly must be deployed to the \Program
>   Files\Microsoft CRM\server\bin\assembly folder on each server where
>   the plug-in is to execute.
>
> Plug-in registration should be done after the assembly has been copied
>   to the …\bin\assembly folder on the server to prevent the situation
>   where a system user causes an event in Microsoft Dynamics CRM to be
>   raised but the registered plug-in assembly does not yet exist on the
>   server. For server database deployment, the plug-in assembly is
>   automatically copied during plug-in registration so that the earlier
>   situation is not an issue.
>
> Depending on your plug-in’s design, your plug-ins may require other
>   referenced assemblies to run. Regardless of whether you deploy your
>   plug-in to the database or disk, if your plug-in requires other
>   assemblies to run, you must put copies of these assemblies in the
>   Global Assembly Cache (GAC) on each server where the plug-in is to
>   execute. This does not apply to a Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online server
>   because you do not have access to the GAC on that server.

See [Register and Deploy Plug-ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309620.aspx#bkmk_deployment)

Comment: Currently we're all on-disk and no GAC for supporting assemblies. We'll have to look into what it'll take to transition and the possible pain points with this route as well. Thanks as always ckeller!